# Optimize MariaDB query with table that self-joins

Tags: optimization, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that I think is taking way too long (as in I've not yet seen it finish!) but I can't figure out why.

The query (which is generated by an application that would be difficult but not impossible to change) is:

```sql
SELECT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, 5 weight
FROM ar1 t1 
INNER JOIN ar1 t2 ON (t2.contact_type = 'Individual' and t1.first_name = t2.first_name) 
WHERE t1.first_name IS NOT NULL
 AND t1.first_name <> ''
 AND t1.contact_type = 'Individual'
 AND t1.id < t2.id GROUP BY id1, id2, weight
```

And a table with 100k rows.

**[EDIT: added:]** The puropse of the query is to provide a list of unique pairs of records that could be duplicates. *Could be* because the table has other fields, too, but this query is only looking at the first name field.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ar1` (                                                                            
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                       
  `contact_type` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,       
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                           
  KEY `k1` (`first_name`,`contact_type`),                                                       
  KEY `k2` (`contact_type`,`first_name`)                                                        
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Table status:

```
Name            | ar1
Engine          | InnoDB
Version         | 10
Row_format      | Dynamic
Rows            | 102463
Avg_row_length  | 46
Data_length     | 4734976
Max_data_length | 0
Index_length    | 5275648
Data_free       | 0
Auto_increment  | <null>
Create_time     | 2020-04-21 09:22:1
Update_time     | <null>
Check_time      | <null>
Collation       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Checksum        | <null>
Create_options  |
```

EXPLAIN says this:

```
***************************[ 1. row ]***************************
id            | 1
select_type   | SIMPLE
table         | t1
type          | ref
possible_keys | PRIMARY,k1,k2
key           | k2
key_len       | 259
ref           | const
rows          | 51232
Extra         | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
***************************[ 2. row ]***************************
id            | 1
select_type   | SIMPLE
table         | t2
type          | ref
possible_keys | PRIMARY,k1,k2
key           | k1
key_len       | 518
ref           | od_civicrm.t1.first_name,const
rows          | 5
Extra         | Using where; Using index
2 rows in set
```

Notes:

- There are only 8647 distinct first names in the table.
- `contact_type` is `Individual` for 99.9% of the rows.
- There's no need to group on a constant (`weight`), either. But ommitting that does not magically fix it either.
- I've tried various index combinations.
- I'm on MariaDB 10.1
- The servers I've tried it on are not massive - but to my mind this is not a huge recordset?

The `ANALYZE` result can be [downloaded](https://safe.artfulrobot.uk/s/sFzaCoDSbCiQbt9)

Comment: Convert the query to
```SELECT DISTINCT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, 5 weight
FROM ar1 t1 
INNER JOIN ar1 t2 ON t1.first_name = t2.first_name 
WHERE t1.first_name IS NOT NULL
  AND t1.first_name <> ''
  AND t1.contact_type = 'Individual'
  AND t2.contact_type = 'Individual' 
  AND t1.id < t2.id```. Add index ```(`contact_type`, `first_name`, `id`)```.

Comment: Worth a go, but that took over twice as long! (462s)

Comment: What about ```SELECT DISTINCT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, 5 weight FROM ar1 t1 INNER JOIN ar1 t2 ON (t1.first_name, t1.contact_type) = (t2.first_name, t1.contact_type) WHERE t1.first_name IS NOT NULL AND t1.first_name <> '' AND t1.contact_type = 'Individual' AND t1.id < t2.id```?

Comment: nope, 451s that one.

Comment: It smacks of "groupwise max" pattern.  And it is being done in a very inefficient way.  See that added tag.

Comment: @Akina - For `JOIN` (as opposed to `LEFT JOIN`, I think `ON` and `WHERE` are equivalent in functionality and speed.  (No I don't know why the OP got 'twice as long'.)

Comment: @Akina - "row constructors" in `WHERE` have been notoriously inefficient.  I don't know when (or even if) your second suggestion will be efficient.

Comment: What is the _intent_ of the query???

Comment: @RickJames thanks, I've edited the question to explain the intent/purpose. It may be related to groupwise max, but it's not the typical situation I've encountered for that problem

Answer (score 1):

What the heck is the intent?  It seems to deliver the `ids` of all pairs of individuals with the same `first_name`.

It looks like a "group-wise" max, but not quite.

`weight` seems to be irrelevant since it is the constant "5".

```
INDEX(contact_type, first_name, id)
```

may speed it up, even with 99.9% of contact_types being the desired value.  The speedup is due to the index being "covering".  The order of the columns is important.

It is likely to return a million rows.  That, in itself, will take time.  And possibly choke the client.

**Just looking for dups?**

Perhaps you want

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), first_name
    FROM t
    WHERE first_name != ''
      AND contact_type = 'Individual'
    GROUP BY first_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Alternatively, `SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id), first_name ...`, except that it does not give you all the ids when there are more than 2.

Optimal:

```
INDEX(contact_type, first_name, id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and apols you didn't have the intent to work with (see edited question now). Your suggestion follows the same pattern as my answer (i.e. use HAVING) which at first I was excited about until I realised it would only give the first possible pair of matches for a given first name, not all pairs. Yours returns all the IDs but in a string, which -to my knowledge- is not possible/sensible to use for other joins; the output format is important because other data will be joined on to both Ids. Changing this query will be hard but changing its required outputs is not poss.

Comment: Interestingly, I did try an index with the ID in it too, as you suggest would be optimal - I thought so too since then *all* the data would be in the index. However MariaDB still chose to use the index without the ID field!

Comment: @artfulrobot - If there are, say, 5 that match, you want 20 rows to list all "pairs"?  Or 10 because of noting that (1,2) and (2,1) are really the same pair?

Comment: I believe the original algorithm gives 10 (because of the `<` constraint on ID)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've reduced it to less than 2s (from ~200s, so a 100× improvement).

```sql
SELECT d1.id, c2.id, 5 weight
  FROM
  (
    SELECT MIN(id) id, first_name
    FROM civicrm_contact c1
    WHERE first_name <> '' AND contact_type = 'Individual'
    GROUP BY c1.first_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) d1
  INNER JOIN civicrm_contact c2 ON c2.first_name = d1.first_name 
     AND c2.id > d1.id AND c2.contact_type = 'Individual'
```

- Note `first_name <> ''` works in place of `IS NOT NULL AND ...` because comparison with `NULL` results in `NULL` and in the `WHERE` context this resolves to boolean false.
- A key on `first_name, contact_type` helped but only very marginally.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't generate every a unique set of every possible combinations of duplicates.